# AG-Grid with vue error in IE11 Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I am using the ag grid community edition with VUE CLI

Everytings working fine on chrome,firefox and safari but I am encountering an error in IE 11

The error says:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"
>
> "Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Here is my code in vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <button @click="getSelectedRows()">Get Selected Rows</button>

    <ag-grid-vue style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
             class="ag-theme-balham"
             :columnDefs="columnDefs"
             :rowData="rowData">
    </ag-grid-vue>
    </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
<script>
import {AgGridVue} from 'ag-grid-vue'
export default {
    components:{
        AgGridVue
    },
    data(){
        return{
            columnDefs:null,
            rowData:null,
            gridApi: null,
            columnApi: null,
            autoGroupColumnDef: null,
        }
    },
    methods : {
        onGridReady : function(params){
            this.gridApi = params.api;
            this.columnApi = params.columnApi;

            
        },
        getSelectedRows : function(){
            const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
            const selectedData = selectedNodes.map(node => node.data);
            const selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedData.map(node => node.make + ' ' + node.model).join(', ');
            console.log(selectedDataStringPresentation);
        }
    },
    beforeMount(){
        this.columnDefs = [
                {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
                {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
                {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
            ];

            this.rowData = [
                {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
                {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
                {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
            ];
        

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appreas that `babel-polyfill` must be imported before ag-grid.